# How to clear query cache to debug query that runs slow the first time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012

I have a query that runs slow the first time it is executed. I want to try to tweak it, but I am having trouble reproducing the problem.

I tried using **`DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`** to see if I could make the query run slow again, but it had no effect. Is there another cache I need to clear to see the bad behavior again? Could it be something else causing my query to run slowly the first time?

Comment: Clear the table and index stat and try again

Comment: @Hiten004, How do I do that?

Comment: `drop statistics Objectname` table or index name  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175075.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use system stored procedure `sp_recompile`

```
Exec sp_recompile 'Table_Name'
GO
```

This will cause all the queries/Stored Procedures/Functions that use a particular table to recompile execution plan when it is executed.

Or if you only want a particular Stored Procedures or Functions to flush all the compiled execution plans you can use that object's name as parameter to sp_recompile

```
Exec sp_recompile 'proc_Name'
GO
```

Sometimes using `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` is not an option as it will flush all of the proc cache and your certainly dont want to do this on a production server or even a Development server where a lot of developers are working.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried using DBCC FREEPROCCACHE to see if I could make the query run
>   slow again, but it had no effect. Is there another cache I need to
>   clear to see the bad behavior again? Could it be something else
>   causing my query to run slowly the first time?

Perhaps it is the data buffer cache that is the issue.  Data pages not already in memory must be read for disk the first time the query runs, but not on subsequent executions because the data is in memory.  Disk assess will obviously slow the query considerably.  You can execute DROPCLEANBUFFERS (preferably on a test server) to remove pages from memory so that pages must read from disk the next time they are accessed and perhaps repeat the initial slowness.

```
USE MyDatabase;
CHECKPOINT;
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
```

From a performance perspective, make sure you've done query an index tuning so that only the data actually needed for the query is touched.  There's not much else you can do to improve performance when disk access is needed, aside from storage subsystem tuning, getting faster disks, or SSD.